# how to iterate over NSCache values in Swift

Tags: swift, loops, dictionary, nscache

I have this class:

```
final class Manager {
    static let shared = NSCache()
}
```

I would like to iterate over all values to eliminate Heavier, how can I do?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213261/how-to-iterate-over-nscache-keys

Comment: Yes i saw, but i would like use swift..